# Updating a <p:column> only renders its child

Tags: primefaces, mojarra

I have a requirement to re-render a <p:column> upon changes in an input located in same row within a <p:panelGrid> nested in a <p:dataTable>:

```
<h:form id="my-form">
<p:dataTable id="my-table" var="item" [...]>
   <p:column [...]>
      <p:panelGrid [...]>
         <p:row id="item-row">
            <p:column id="item-question-column" styleClass="#{item.valueSet ? '' : 'value_not_set'}">
                <p:outputLabel id="item-question-column-label" value="#{item.questionNumberLabel}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <p:selectOneRadio id="radio" value="#{item.value}">
                    <f:selectItems var="option" value="#{item.options}" itemLabel="#{option.label}" itemValue="#{option.value}" />
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="item-question-column" />
                </p:selectOneRadio>
            </p:column>
         </p:row>
      </p:panelGrid>
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The basic idea is that after the model has been updated, the `item-question-column` is updated via ajax and the style class is updated.

The above code generates the following HTML for the `item-question-column`:

```
<td id="my-form:my-table:0:item-question-column" role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell value_not_set">
   <label id="my-form:my-table:0:item-question-column-label" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">1</label>
</td>
```

This is as expected. Now, when I select a radio button, the ajax change is triggered and updates the `item-question-column` component, but the resulting HTML for the `item-question-column` is:

```
<label id="my-form:my-table:0:item-question-column-label" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">1</label>
```

The enclosing `td` has disappeared during the update, leaving the layout messed up.

If I update the entire row (`item-row`), which of course is rendered as a `tr`, the rendering ends up correct, but I cannot use this method as this will also re-render the radio buttons and discard some jQuery'ed onChange-code that I apply on jQuery.ready().

If the solution to my problem has something to do with needing to update a parent component, what JSF/Primefaces component can I use as a wrapper for a the `item-question-column`?

Using Primefaces 10 on Mojarra 2.4.0

Comment: I actually did not think you could update an indivdual column I had never tried it before because the way the table renders its seems odd that would work.  What happens if you just update the whole datatable?

Comment: @Melloware, that would definitely work, but this is not a feasible solution as this would also re-render the inputs hence discarding the jQuery'ed onChange-code that I apply on jQuery.ready().

Comment: put styleClass inside wrapper element and use PrimeFaces selectors?

Comment: <p:column><span class="my-selector-class"><p:outputLabel id="item-question-column-label" value="#{item.questionNumberLabel}" styleClass="#{item.valueSet ? '' : 'value_not_set'}" /></span></p:column>

Comment: <p:ajax event="change" update="@(.my-selector-class)" /> will update EVERY my-selector-class you can fine-grain it to update that row only

Comment: if you use row index for class name, like class="my-selector-class-row#{rowIndexVar} and update="my-selector-class-row#{rowIndexVar}" i think it should work (not completely sure, but i know i managed to update single cell somehow)

Comment: yeah i did somthing like <p:dataTable ... rowIndexVar="rn"> ... and inside inputField i say <p:ajax process="myInputFieldId:@row(#{rn})" update="my-output-field-selector-class-#{rn}" because i want ROW to be processed, and single outputText in same row only to be updated. and ofcourse outputText styleClass="my-output-field-selector-class-#{rn}"

Comment: @Nikola, thank you for your comments. I have tried using jQuery targeted updating also, but this results in the same problem: the enclosing <td> is simply not being rendered on update. If I target another <p:column> the result is similar broken. I can update the <p:outputLabel id="item-question-column-label"> correctly, so my issue seems to be relating to targeting <p:column> elements, but not other elements. Could this be a bug in Primefaces?